# Google Docs surface engine

Tags: javascript, text, documentation, editor

Is there any link to a more in-depth details about the Google Docs layout engine? If it uses webgl, or the canvas element 2d context, or anything. I know google did it from scratch calculating character width and all.

I was reading about Bespin and it said it had some performance issues, so I was wondering what google did to make it fast.
I just can't find any details about how they did.

Only if it was open source...

Btw, I tried benjamn / kix-standalone but the source code from github is simply not readble:

```
function $a(a) { 
    return Wa(a) == Ta 
} 
function ab(a) { 
    var b = Wa(a); 
    return b == Ta || b == Ra && typeof a.length == Sa <br/>
}
```

Comment: i did some research in this topic last year. i faved your question and will answer as soon as i can find the time. For the time, have a look at [Surface](https://github.com/substance/surface)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time :)

Answer (score 2):

Google Docs captures all of your input in a hidden input element and/or via keyboard and mouse events, and then lays out the contents of the document onto your screen via a custom surface and layout engine implemented completely in Javascript.

Everything on the display from text to the cursor itself consists of DOM elements. For example, the cursor is not rendered by the browser directly, but instead by a 1-pixel wide div that is positioned at the correct spot. You can use the Inspect functionality of Chrome to look at the DOM created by Google Docs to see the result of this engine in action. See also this blog post from the Google Docs product manager for more details: http://googledrive.blogspot.ca/2010/05/whats-different-about-new-google-docs.html. As you mentioned in the question, the character widths needed for this type of cursor positioning are calculated on the fly.

To get a little more insight it might be helpful to look at the implementation of a similar (though obviously simpler) project: [Ritzy](http://ritzyed.github.io/ritzy/) is a new open source rich text editor that contains a custom javascript surface and layout engine just like Google Docs. Its DOM manipulation uses [Facebook React](https://facebook.github.io/react/). As far as I know, this is the first open source implementation of this technique. It contains Google-docs-like calculations for character widths and cursor positioning (see [TextFontMetrics.js](https://github.com/ritzyed/ritzy/blob/master/src/core/TextFontMetrics.js)), and could serve as a useful learning tool.

**Disclaimer**: I am the author of the above-mentioned project.